# Save function output to variable for Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing some issues with Firebase and Android. I want to save a function's output to a variable which I want to use later, but I am not sure how to give the correct parameters for the functions.

```
public void getBasicData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot textViewDataGet) {

    textViewDataGet = dataSnapshot.child("Users").getValue();
}
```

In the function above I have already declared a string called textViewDataGet and the libraries are all imported correctly. I have tried to implement a basic write function to the database. But AndroidStudio doesn't want to work with the string. However, if I remove the variable and leave it without it, no errors are being shown. Thanks in advance!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first have to make an instance using **getInstance** and declare a data reference which you will use to access the data of the database.

```
FirebaseDatabase dbDay = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference day = dbDay.getReference("Day");
```

This was the only way I could find how to do it by checking when the data is changed

```
day.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
int value = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
textViewDataGet = value;

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the method return void, make it return a `String` so that you can save it for later use. This is because Java is strictly pass-by-value.

When you declare a parameter for a function and then pass it to a function you are actually passing the address of the variable not the variable itself so any change you make to the parameter will affect it only in the function and not outside. As a solution, you can try the following

```
public String getBasicData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    return dataSnapshot.child("Users").getValue();
}
```

And then you can use it where appropriate like that

```
textViewDataGet = getBasicData(dataSnapshot);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried it but it gives me 3 errors, it says that there is no variable like dataSnapshot and that it expected a string and not an object in the fucntion "getBasicData"